# How to bind multiple interfaces to a raw socket

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel

I have opened a raw socket to get all the raw packets:

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)
```

When a packet is received on an interface which is member of a LAG or bond, the kernel is sending the packets to the user application 2 times. One for the actual physical interface and another one for the bond interface. How can I restrict the kernel to lift the packet only for the interface which I am interested?

We can achieve it by binding the application interested interface to the socket. But I don't want to create multiple sockets (one for each interface) to avoid scalability issue.  Is it possible to bind multiple interface to the raw socket dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Use SO_BINDTODEVICE socket option to bind to specific interface:

```
char *iface = "eth0";
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, iface, 4);
```

In this case you'll have to create separate socket for each interface.

Alternative solution would be to use [bind(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) with INADDR_ANY.

You do not have a third option.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The man page for `socket(7)` says that `SO_BINDTODEVICE` "works only for some socket types, particularly AF_INET sockets.  It is not supported for packet sockets (use normal bind(2) there)."  Unfortunately, I can't get `bind` to do the right thing, either.